# Access the database from another LAMP

Tags: php, networking, xampp, localhost, lamp

I have two LAMP installations, one is 7.1 and another is 5.4. Mistakenly I have copied one really big DB in lampp 7.1 instead of 5.4. So now I am worry about is there any way that I can port it to 5.4 or use it directly from 7.1.

It will be hard for me to again import this. Is there any way?

Comment: Ok thanks for edit.

Comment: Do you have both MySQL instances running at the same time? You will probably need to change the port number of one of them, to prevent a port clash. Then you will be able to connect to one from the other, just by specifying the correct port number in your connection string.